# Why create an empty class, then instantiate it and set some attributes?

Tags: python, class, instance, instantiation, instance-variables

[html2txt](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/html2text.py) contains the following code:

```
class Storage: pass
options = Storage()
options.google_doc = False
options.ul_item_mark = '*'
```

I've not seen such an approach before. What's the benefit/use of this approach over setting up the attributes in `__init__()`, and is a class even necessary here?

Comment: Given the name it appears to be used an 'ad-hoc class': a bag of properties, for some localized meaning, without explicitly using a Dictionary. This avoids having to use proper values (eg. strings) for keys. Ruby has `ostruct` and JavaScript objects implicitly act as such.

Comment: Other use cases include dynamically overriding object methods/attributes or creating mock objects (duck-typing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you want to store some collection of named data. You could use a `dict` but you like the look of dotted attributes in a class object. Just create the most boring class possible and use python's native attribute assignment to do the trick. It is usually a question of aesthetics.

Comment: *It is usually a question of aesthetics* - I thought as much.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the attributes ahead of time you can use namedtuples for this kind of functionality.

From the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
EmployeeRecord = namedtuple('EmployeeRecord', 'name, age, title, department, paygrade')
```

Comment: ...if you know all of the information in advance and nothing changes.

Comment: @tdelaney Not sure what you mean. You can dynamically add to a namedtuple as well. I could loop through a set of attribute names and attach attributes e.g. EmployeeRecord.home_address = '123 Main St.' Anyway, in OP's post the information IS known ahead of time.

Comment: No, you can't (re your reply to @tdelaney). You can *if* you subclass `namedtuple`, but that's not how `namedtuple` is supposed to be used. You are not using it as a tuple, just as any old namespace. Use `SimpleNamespace` for that case, new in Python 3.3: [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#additional-utility-classes-and-functions)

Comment: No, you cannot add anything dynamcally... its a `tuple` after all. You get one shot to create the objects by supplying the values to the constructor. No changes, no additions.

Comment: @alexhb `type(namedtuple)` is `<class 'function'>` meaning only that it is a factory function. How about actually trying it? ` Foo=namedtuple('Foo', 'a b c');foo=Foo(1,2,3);foo.a=2` results in `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

Comment: @tdelaney Give this a try: `type(EmployeeRecord)`. Once you construct the namedtuple as in `EmployeeRecord('alex', '29')` then you cannot add attributes on the fly.

Comment: @alexhb  - well sure, you can add attributes to the class object which makes it like most other class objects out there. How about `lxml.etree.XMLSchemaError` or even `os.walk`. You can add attributes to lots of things.

Comment: `collections.namedtuple` doesn't create a namedtuple. It creates a namedtuple creator. You get the namedtuple when you instantiate it.

Comment: @tdelaney Absolutely. And you're right, adding attrs to the namedtuple before it's instantiated is mostly useless. The boon and burden of duck typing. Maybe it's the statically-typed programmer in me, but when you have cases where the attributes are known I think it's probably more pythonic to just have a namedtuple. Self-documenting, less cruft, etc. Anyway, glad I said something because I did not know about SimpleNamespace.